# MySQL crashed for unknown reason and doesn't start even with innodb_force_recovery=6

Tags: mysql, database-administration

The service starts and stops after a few seconds. The setting innodb_force_recovery=6 doesn't help. Previously it had been crashing due to an electricity outage 2 months ago, but I was able to restore everything, and then it worked well for 2 following months. But now it seems to be a more serious and low-level issue. Could you please help?
The full error dump is here:

```
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2022-10-24T07:14:00.931490Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--ssl=off' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use --tls-version=invalid instead.
2022-10-24T07:14:00.931754Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010097] [Server] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2022-10-24T07:14:00.931858Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 11348
2022-10-24T07:14:00.957031Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-10-24T07:14:05.020472Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-10-24T07:14:06.443189Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011302] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Failed at SSL configuration: "SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key"'
2022-10-24T07:14:06.445335Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2022-10-24T07:14:06.445535Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.30'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-10-24T07:14:46.604890Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: fsp0fsp.cc:2152:inode thread 3196
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
07:14:46 UTC - mysqld got exception 0x16 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x2cf63dc87d0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
7ff755370858    mysqld.exe!?my_print_stacktrace@@YAXPEBEK@Z()
7ff75450e92b    mysqld.exe!?print_fatal_signal@@YAXH@Z()
7ff75450e6f3    mysqld.exe!?my_server_abort@@YAXXZ()
7ff7553547fa    mysqld.exe!?my_abort@@YAXXZ()
7ff75559ca99    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff75555c866    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff75555c46e    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff7554640f2    mysqld.exe!??$endl@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AEAV10@@Z()
7ff755466d8d    mysqld.exe!??$endl@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AEAV10@@Z()
7ff755465e2f    mysqld.exe!??$endl@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AEAV10@@Z()
7ff755465ccb    mysqld.exe!??$endl@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AEAV10@@Z()
7ff7554630c8    mysqld.exe!??$endl@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AEAV10@@Z()
7ff755474202    mysqld.exe!??$endl@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AEAV10@@Z()
7ff755477cc4    mysqld.exe!??$endl@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AEAV10@@Z()
7ff75553033d    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7fffe04d1bb2    ucrtbase.dll!_configthreadlocale()
7fffe0807034    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
7fffe27026a1    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): 
Connection ID (thread ID): 0
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Comment: "A value of 6 is considered drastic because database pages are left in an obsolete state, which in turn may introduce more corruption into B-trees and other database structures." Can you dump your tables?

Comment: IT doesn't start with any innodb_force_recovery status

Comment: So you also tried with --innodb_force_recovery = 4?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It did start with --innodb_force_recovery = 4

Comment: Please ask database admin related questions on the dedicated DBA sister site of SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend starting with `--innodb_force_recovery = 4`, dump all your tables, and start with a fresh installation of MySQL. Reimport them. Also, check the disk for errors, maybe because of the power outage, it's a physical problem with the disk and the data was corrupted.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to start MySQL and dump everything. So I have to reinstall and import from the dump, and I believe it will solve that problem.